# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS fuerte sdf

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to switch between ROS electric and ROS fuerte. My problem is in launching the '.launch' file since the shell says that my model is deprecated (originally it was a '.xacro' file).

Does anybody know how to convert it into a new ROS format without rewriting by scratch my model?

Thank you,

Neostek

P.S. I also tried with the 'gzsdf' command following this guide

http://answers.ros.org/question/41766/gazebo-urdf-deprecated/

The real problem is the model misses some parts and the warning message Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element Warning [parser.cc:291] DEPRECATED GAZEBO MODEL FILE On July 1st, 2012, this formate will no longer by supported continues to appear

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/59/ros-fuerte-sdf/) by [Neostek](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48/neostek/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The old Gazebo model files (prior to Gazebo 1.0) must be converted manually. ROS Electric used a version of Gazebo that was less than 1.0, so your world and model files must be converted manually.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0